# Powershell: Start Process with execution time limit and read from its StdOut while running

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to launch a process (eg. ping) in PowerShell, set a execution time limit and kill the process if it hasn't terminated before the time deadline is hit.

I have a script which can start an process and terminate it after x seconds (easy) and a script which starts a process and reads from its StdOut when its done (easy).

My code to stop a process after x seconds

```bsh
$p = Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -PassThru
Wait-Process -InputObject $p -Timeout 3
Stop-Process -InputObject $p
```

My code to start a process and read from its StdOut

```bsh
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Property @{
        FileName = "ping.exe"
        Arguments = "-t 127.0.0.1"
        RedirectStandardOutput = $true
        UseShellExecute =$false
    }
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $outevent = Register-ObjectEvent -Action {Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.Data} -InputObject $p -EventName OutputDataReceived
    $p.Start()
    $p.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

But I can't manage to get those two functionalities together into one script. Usually the StdOut reading is blocking the timer. I'd like to run a .exe for x seconds and read any StdOut produced in that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve what you're looking for via background jobs. For example:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    ping.exe 8.8.8.8
}

$TimeOutSeconds = 5

1..$TimeoutSeconds | ForEach-Object {
    $Job | Receive-Job
    if (($Job | Get-Job).State -eq 'completed') {
        Break
    }
    Else {
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
} -End { Write-Warning 'Timeout reached.' }

$Job | Receive-Job

Stop-Job $Job -PassThru | Remove-Job
```

**Explanation:**

- The `Start-Job` cmdlet creates a background job that executes the defined script block. The cmdlet returns a `PSRemotingJob` object that we return to `$Job` to use to reference the job elsewhere in the script.
- A `ForEach-Object` loop is use to iterate 5 times with a 1 second delay on each iteration and each time uses the `Receive-Job` cmdlet to retrieve any output that the background job has produced.
- If the job has reached a completed state (e.g the execution has ended) then we break the loop. If this occurs the `-End` scriptblock of the `ForEach-Object` is never executed.
- After the 5th iteration the `-End` block executes and warns the user that we've reached the timeout.
- We then retrieve any final output from the job and then stop and remove it.